# How can we convert uploaded docx file to pdf in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-conversion, filefield

I have created a model which accepts file. I'm trying to convert the uploaded docx file to pdf and display it to the user.
for the conversion of docx file to pdf I'm trying to use docxtopdf module of python.
But when I pass my file from `request.FILES['Doc]` to convert function it gives error :

```
TypeError at /convview/
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile
```

Here i the code from views.py file:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        pdffile=UserConvert(Doc=request.FILES['Doc'])
        pdffile.save()
        convert(pdffile.Doc)
```

How can we change mime type of files when it is in memory?

Comment: it depends upon the server where your django backend is hosted.
Docx to PDF conversion needs windows microsoft word or libreoffice word on linux

Comment: i wanted to know how can we pass the file to  docxtopdf convert function for converion as above error is generated  related to filefield.

Comment: Please post also the 'UserConvert()' funxtion

Comment: UserConvert is the model class :  'class UserConvert(models.Model):
       Doc=models.FileField(upload_to='documents',blank=True )'

Comment: Sorry the convert function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `FieldFile` to the function but a str, bytes or a path is expected:

```
TypeError expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FieldFile
```

You need to get the path of the file with the `path` parameters:

```
convert(pdffile.Doc.path)
```